# Java multi-thread matrix multiplication

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, thread-synchronization

Trying to get a multi-threaded matrix multiplication to work in Java. It is given a (m x n) matrix, a (n x k) matrix and 't' threads to perform the operation on.

My program works when the matrices are square and t == n. When running with t < n, the other threads do not pick up the additional operations, and it returns a partially completed matrix. When the matrices are not square, the additional threads return array out of bounds errors and do not run. I would really appreciate any advice. Here are the relevant code snippets

Beginning threads. multipliers is an array of MatrixMultiplier, a class defined later.

```
Multiply multiply = new Multiply(cols_mat, rows_mat2);

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    multipliers[i] = new MatrixMultiplier(multiply);
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    my_threads[i] = new Thread(multipliers[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    my_threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    my_threads[i].join();
}
```

Multiply class which defines the matrix multiplication

```
class Multiply extends MatrixMultiplication {
    private int i;
    private int j;
    private int chance;

    public Multiply(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        chance = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void multiplyMatrix() {
        int sum = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < j; b++) {
                sum = sum + mat[chance][b] * mat2[b][a];
            }
            result[chance][a] = sum;
        }

        if (chance >= i)
            return;
        chance++;
    }
}
```

And the matrix multiplier

```
class MatrixMultiplier implements Runnable {
    private final Multiply mul;

    public MatrixMultiplier(Multiply mul) {
        this.mul = mul;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mul.multiplyMatrix();
    }
}
```

Where I personally think the issue lies is with `if (chance >= i) return;` but I have not found a way to incorporate a thread's column responsibilities with the program still working. Again, any advice pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

The t threads assume that only t multiplications are required to produce your result matrix.  This is not to be the case when m != k or t != m or t != k.  The threads are worker threads that will only process your requests.  I would consider making each MatrixMultiplier have access to the mxn, nxk, mxk matrices and a rolcolumn entries container.

```
class MatricMultiplier {
    private double a[][], b[][], results[][];
    private Queue<..> entries;
    ....
}
```

The run method will then use the entries container to calculate the sum for a given <row,column> entry of the resulting mxk matrix.  The run method could become:

```
run() {
    for (Entry entry = entries.poll(); entry != null; entry = entries.poll()) {
        int row = entry.row;
        int col = entry.col;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a[row].length; i++) {
            sum += a[row][i] * b[i][col];
        }
        results[row][col] = sum;
    }
}
```

There are three things to note here that is different than what you have.

1. you are not using a synchronization block
2. each entry is calculating the answer for a unique row/column of the result matrix
3. the Multiple class is not required any longer

You can then create t threads that process each entry in the entries container and will exit when the entries container is empty.

Note that the entries container should be one of the concurrent Queue containers available in the java.util.concurrent package.

The remaining task is how to create the rowcolumn entries container.  Here is some code that you could use:

```
Queue<..> entries = new Concurrent...<..>();
int rowSize = a.length;
int colSize = b[0].length;
for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++) {
        entries.add(new RowColumnEntry(row, col));
    }
}
```

Noting that the `a` and `b` are the `m×n` and `n×k` matrices.

Hope this helps.